# form error - bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm having some trouble with a form the last element doesn't fit properly, this is my code:

[image]

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="2a">
    <div *ngFor="let perso of person">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Fecha de Ingreso:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="condo" value="{{perso.fecha_ini}}" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Fecha de Salida:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="condo" id="condo" value="{{perso.fecha_fin}}" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Foto:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!-- <input type="text" name="condo" value="{{perso.ruta_foto}}" class="form-control"> -->
                <img src="http://52.14.193.170/imagenes/pers/2.jpg" alt="Odlir" width="130" height="130">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Antecedentes Penales:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="condo" value="{{perso.ruta_penal}}" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Antecedentes Policiales:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="condo" value="{{perso.ruta_policial}}" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Antecedentes Policiales:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="condo" value="{{perso.ruta_policial}}" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

i don't know what i'm doing wrong, any ideas why this is happening? any help would be appreciated, im using bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: There's not enough html/css to reproduce this to help. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know [what you have tried so far to solve your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Comment: This is the result of what you have supplied so far: https://jsfiddle.net/aw8ezexy/

Comment: turned out the width wasn't big enough so I made it bigger and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still okay with

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va +PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVa4B.png

Comment: thank you made me realize some property I added was the problem